# Weird behavior while react hook state management, splice() removes wrong element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a state which I use for adding new JSX elements:

```
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState<IDisplay>({
            BookingFormDropDown: [],
        }
    );
```

Adding element onClick() with this function from render():

```
    const addNewService = () => {
        setDisplay(
            (prevState: IDisplay) => (
                {
                    ...prevState, BookingFormDropDown: [...prevState.BookingFormDropDown,
                        <div>
                            <BookingFormDropDown bookingData={bookingData}/>
                        </div>]
                }
            )
        );

    };
```

Looping and retrieving these JSX elements in render() in this way:

```
                display.BookingFormDropDown.map((el: JSX.Element, i: number) => {
                    return <div key={i}>
                        <div>{el}</div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div>
                                <button type="button"
                                        onClick={() => handelRemoveService(i)}>Remove
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })
```

Why my application always removes last element on any button click? 
As far as I understand after adding a new element to the array application should loop display.BookingFormDropDown again and new index values should be passed for each button while map().

```
    const handelRemoveService = (i: number) => {
        const state: JSX.Element[] = display.BookingFormDropDown;
        state.splice(i, 1);
        setDisplay(
            (prevState: IDisplay) => ({
                ...prevState, BookingFormDropDown: state
            })
        );
    };
```

Just today decided to implement hooks, class-based component works fine with a similar logic.

Full component code:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent, useState} from 'react';
import './BookingForm.css';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import Slots from "../../components/Slots/Slots";
import ClientDetails from "../../components/ClientDetails";
import BookingFormDropDown from "../../components/BookingFormDropDrown";

//import {IService, IServiceCategory, IEmployee, ISlot} from "../../interfaces/IBookingFrom";

export interface IBookingData {
    Location: string[] //ILocation[]
    Categories: string[] //ICategory[]
    Services: string[] //IService[]
    Employees: string[] //IEmployee[]
    Slots: string[] //ISlot[]
    date: Date[] | Date
}

interface IDisplay {
    BookingFormDropDown: JSX.Element[]
    BookingStage: string | null
    Mode: string | null
    error: string | null
}

const BookingForm: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [bookingData, setBookingData] = useState<IBookingData>({
        Location: ['t', 'l', 'r'],
        Categories: ['one', 'two', 'tree'],
        Services: ['one1', 'two1', 'tree1'],
        Employees: ['one2', 'two2', 'tree2'],
        Slots: ['Mon 12:00', 'Mon 14:01', 'Mon 15:02', 'Mon 12:03',
            'Mon 14:04', 'Mon 15:05', 'Mon 12:06', 'Mon 14:07', 'Mon 15:08',
            'Mon 15:09', 'Mon 12:10', 'Mon 14:11', 'Mon 15:12', 'Mon 12:13',
            'Mon 14:14', 'Mon 15:15'],
        date: new Date()
    });

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState<IDisplay>({
            BookingFormDropDown: [],
            BookingStage: null,
            Mode: null,
            error: null
        }
    );

    const handelRemoveService = (i: number) => {
        const state: JSX.Element[] = display.BookingFormDropDown;
        state.splice(i, 1);
        setDisplay(
            (prevState: IDisplay) => ({
                ...prevState, BookingFormDropDown: state
            })
        );
    };


    const addNewService = () => {
        setDisplay(
            (prevState: IDisplay) => (
                {
                    ...prevState, BookingFormDropDown: [...prevState.BookingFormDropDown,
                        <div>
                            <BookingFormDropDown bookingData={bookingData}/>
                        </div>]
                }
            )
        );

    };

    const handleNewDate = (newDate: Date[] | Date) => setBookingData({
        ...bookingData, date: newDate

    });

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <h1 className="col">Demo place</h1>
            </div>

            <BookingFormDropDown bookingData={bookingData}/>

            {/* Displaying  additional services from array*/
                display.BookingFormDropDown.map((el: JSX.Element, i: number) => {
                    return <div key={i}>
                        <div>{el}</div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col mb-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <button type="button" className="col-md-2 btn btn-light"
                                        onClick={() => handelRemoveService(i)}>Remove
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })
            }

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col mb-4 d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <button type="button" className="col-md-2 btn btn-light"
                            onClick={() => addNewService()}>Add service
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <Calendar minDetail={'year'}
                              onChange={handleNewDate}
                              value={bookingData.date}/>
                </div>

                <Slots list={bookingData.Slots}/>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col d-flex justify-content-center p-5">
                    <button type="button" className=" col-md-3 btn btn-light">NEXT</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ClientDetails/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BookingForm;
```

Comment: can you show code for: handelRemoveService

Comment: Added to the description, forgot to add )

Comment: do you maybe use useCallback or useMemo?  can you provide full code for the problematic component. also index keys where elements change is a bad idea: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop/ . Do you maybe use some inner state in BookingFormDropDown? (for display purpose)

Comment: Full code added. BookingFormDropDown component has no state, just receive these props. In my case map index and handelRemoveService() have the same index since they are correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it removes the last element? I see that all your elements are created with the same data, can you validate that really the last element is removed? (since index is your key it will always look like the last element is removed since length is now: prevLength -1). Here is a dummy example that shows that your code is ok: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-me4si

Also just a tip:

```
   const handelRemoveService = (i: number) => {
        const state: JSX.Element[] = display.BookingFormDropDown;
        state.splice(i, 1);
        setDisplay(
            (prevState: IDisplay) => ({
                ...prevState, BookingFormDropDown: state
            })
        );
    };
```

you are mutating the original BookingFormDropDown (if you had some code that depended on that you would be in trouble). When changing state it is always advisable to create a new reference:

```
const state: JSX.Element[] = [...display.BookingFormDropDown];
```

Comment: Actually you are right, code work as expected added counter for a test. But Max is right as well. I will not be able to listen changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using indexes as keys for lists where you remove or add items in the middle. Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

Another thing not related to your question: don't put JSX elements in state. Only raw serializable data belongs to state. You should only create JSX while rendering

---

added based on comments, why storing jsx in state is not a good idea:

1. it's not reactive. In your example, you create BookingFormDropDown by calling addNewService function and that BookingFormDropDown will freeze in this state forever. It will never update based on anything. You render it once and reuse result of that render forever. `bookingData` prop is now useless as its changes will not be reflected
2. you lose data. If you, for example, had different types of `BookingFormDropDown`s in that state, you wouldn't be able to e.g. count them by type, or filter, or reorder. In your case you can't even extract proper unique keys from your elements, because you don't know what these elements are. They are black boxes now, all you have are their indexes, which are causing the problem you described in your question. Doing anything based on created dropdowns is now impossible
3. you can't properly inspect your state in devtools, or serialize it to save in localstorage

Comment: Could you please share more details about storing JSX in state. Why it's not a good idea?

Comment: You are right I will not be able to listen changes. Will chnage the logic. But currelty code work as expected.